# How to install gcc-4.9 on ubuntu 17.10(artful)

Tags: 17.10, gcc, g++

can someone help me to install gcc/g++ 4.9 on artful?

there is no package for artful in repository

just for 16.04(Xenial) and 17.04(Zesty)

Comment: which gcc is in Artful? Why do you have to have the older one?

Comment: If no package then you will have to build it yourself if you know what your doing!

Comment: the defualt gcc in artful is 7.2, but some project need 4.8+ to build,, i was install gcc4.8, just confuse why i can't find 4.9 package for artful

Comment: Do you really need 4.9 for some reason? You almost certainly shouldn't be using it to build software in a recent Ubuntu.

Comment: ok thanks, for some reason my friend told me 4.8 just fine, 4.9 have a lot of bugs, sorry to waste your time

Comment: `nvcc` is complaining to me `#error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc versions later than 5 are not supported!`

Comment: Torch is giving `Found GCC 5, installing GCC 4.9` and then `Package 'gcc-4.9' has no installation candidate`